# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ']' in D:\wamp64\www\PROJETOS-\sist-crop\jcrop\m2brimagem.class.php on line 40

Tags: php, array

Como arrumo esse erro de sintaxe?

```
$this->extensoes_validas = $extensoes_validas ['jpg','jpeg','jpe','gif','bmp','png'];
```

O que eu queria era atribuir essa array a `$this->extensoes_validas`

Comment: Francisco, bem-vindo! Acho que ambas as respostas resolvem o teu problema. Uma com sintaxe `array(..)` outra com sintaxe `[...]` mas fazem a mesma coisa. Escolhe uma e clica no simbolo para aceitar a resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É erro de sintaxe. Isso resolve o problema:

```
$extensoes_validas = array('jpg','jpeg','jpe','gif','bmp','png');
$this->extensoes_validas = $extensoes_validas;
```

Comment: valeu leandro  pela força funcionou legalzinho , cara eu não conheço esse tipo de atribuição com cochetes , que o valor fica dentro e atrbui com a seta e igual , não vi tambem nos cursos por ai , os caras deveriam ensinar isso.

Comment: De nada @Francisco. Depois leia esse [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), é referente o que você deve fazer quando alguém responde sua pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

O correto seria:

```
$this->extensoes_validas = ['jpg','jpeg','jpe','gif','bmp','png'];
```

Caso queira acessar algum índice específico deste array, pode usar o seguinte:

```
echo $this->extensoes_validas[0]; // jpg
echo $this->extensoes_validas[1]; // jpeg
```

E assim por diante.

Comment: Isso não responde a dúvida dele.

Comment: O erro está ocorrendo porque ele está fazendo a atribuição da forma errada. Se atribuir usando corretamente a sintaxe dos colchetes, não ocorrerá o erro.

Comment: isso mesmo Danilo , valeu pela força mas a sua atribuição tambem não funcionou, usei a debaixo , cara eu não conheço esse tipo de atribuição  nos cursos de php por ai , somente olhando codigos  prontos os caras o deveriam passar isso para os alunos..